# Binding multiple functions to a view's click event

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to bind a couple of functions to a click event. Here's what I've got:

```
var Foreground = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

    el: $('body'),

    events: {
        'click': 'tryResetContextMenu onClickDeselectCollections'
    },

    //  Whenever the user clicks on any part of the UI that isn't a multi-select item, deselect the multi-select items.
    onClickDeselectCollections: function (event) {
        console.log("deselect collections");
        var isMultiSelectItem = $(event.target).hasClass('multiSelectItem');
        var isChildMultiSelectItem = $(event.target).closest('.multiSelectItem').length > 0;

        if (!isMultiSelectItem && !isChildMultiSelectItem) {
            this.deselectCollections();
        }
    },

    //  If a click occurs and the default isn't prevented, reset the context menu groups to hide it.
    //  Child elements will call event.preventDefault() to indicate that they have handled the context menu.
    tryResetContextMenu: function (event) {
        console.log("resetting context menu items");
        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {

            //  TODO: I don't think this is the proper way to do this. I should be showing a new view with top/left defined?
            this.contextMenu.currentView.show({
                top: event.pageY,
                //  Show the element just slightly offset as to not break onHover effects.
                left: event.pageX + 1
            });

        } else {

            //  Clearing the groups of the context menu will cause it to become hidden.
            ContextMenuItems.reset();
        }
    }
});
```

Both functions don't fire, but work fine individually. Is this functionality supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do like this :

```
events: {
    'click': function(event) {
                 this.tryResetContextMenu(event);
                 this.onClickDeselectCollections(event);
             }
},
```

Comment: This would seem to imply that it is supported using just a string, though: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/commit/ce803e90c2ffa1fa44d5f4c37409fab9a0636fca

Comment: Maybe in `Marionette.modelEvents` but when you use `events:` you are using `Backbone.View.events` and Backbone don't support multiple functions in events callback.